# why `docker run -d centos tail -f /dev/null` command can keep the docker container running in the background?

Tags: docker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6HKk.png)

This evening, by checking the data, I learned that to make the docker container run in the background, you should add `tail - f /dev/null` after the command. However, I don't understand the meaning of each letter in the command `tail - f /dev/null`. I only know that it can make the docker container run in the background. I want to know the meaning of each letter in the command `tail - f /dev/null`,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your command. Remove the whitespace between - and f then it should work.

tail is responsible to read the last 10 lines of a file -f parameter means follow all lines which will be added to the file.

This is the reason why the terminal will stay open.

/dev/null is a Linux device.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely. It is true that there is a whitespace between - and f. I did some research just now. /dev/null is an empty device. It is also called bit bucket or black hole(just as the brother downstairs mentioned). Any input data will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `tail -f /dev/null`

From `man tail`:

```
DESCRIPTION
       Print the last 10 lines of each FILE to standard output.
.
.
.
-f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
          output appended data as the file grows;

          an absent option argument means 'descriptor'
```

`/dev/null` is a virtual device file that will appear to `tail` as if it were a "normal" file.

In plain English, this will make `tail` keep waiting for new data in `/dev/null`, but there will never be any since it's a special type of device (essentially a black hole).

Comment: Your answer was very detailed. At present,My reputation hasn’t reached to 15. I really want to vote yes for you. Thanks for your sincere answer.